# Add code to ENHANCEMENT-SECTION .. SPOTS ... INCLUDE BOUND

Tags: abap

I need to add some code in ENHANCEMENT-SECTION. It looks as follows:

[image: example]

It is possible or not?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add your own code here.

First, click the enhancement button (looks like a little spiral) then click on the name of the enhancement section (ABRUFMENGE_01) and then click the Create* button.  This will prompt you to create your own enhancement.

You should know - enhancement sections will overwrite the original code.  SAP should default your new enhancement implementation with the original code - just remember, only your code will execute.

You should probably read the [documentation on enhancements](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abensource_code_enhancement.htm).

*Depending on your version, you might not have a create button - you might need to right-click on the enhancement name -> enhancement operations -> create implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Yes it is possible.  But you need an access key from your basis people.  To avoid needing the access key, you might be able to find an implicit enhancement.

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAP/How+to+do+Explicit+Enhancement

Comment: You do not need a basis key to use an enhancement section.